# "Can't resolve 'syncfusion-javascript'" Webpack - Aurelia

Tags: javascript, webpack, aurelia, syncfusion

I'm trying to integrate Syncfusions' Js library with an Aurelia project using the Aurelia Syncfusion Bridge, but i'm getting the following error when trying to load the plugin into my vendor package.

> ERROR in dll vendor
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'syncfusion-javascript' in 'C:\Users\Liam\Downloads\aurelia-webpack1333503894'
>        @ dll vendor

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { AureliaPlugin, ModuleDependenciesPlugin } = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');
const bundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    return [{
        stats: { modules: false },
        entry: { 'app': 'aurelia-bootstrapper' },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
            modules: ['ClientApp', 'node_modules'],
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(bundleOutputDir),
            publicPath: 'dist/',
            filename: '[name].js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/i, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'ts-loader?silent=true' },
                { test: /\.html$/i, use: 'html-loader' },
                { test: /\.css$/i, use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|cur|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' },
                { test: /\.woff2(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'url-loader', query: { limit: 10000, mimetype: 'application/font-woff2' } },
                { test: /\.woff(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'url-loader', query: { limit: 10000, mimetype: 'application/font-woff' } },
                { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|otf)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'file-loader' },

            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({ IS_DEV_BUILD: JSON.stringify(isDevBuild) }),
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            }),
            new AureliaPlugin({ aureliaApp: 'boot' }),

        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]')  // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    }];
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
const { AureliaPlugin, ModuleDependenciesPlugin } = require('aurelia-
webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');

module.exports = ({ prod } = {}) => {
const isDevBuild = !prod;

return [{
    stats: { modules: false },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
            { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, loader: extractCSS.extract([isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize']) }
        ]
    },
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            'aurelia-event-aggregator',
            'aurelia-fetch-client',
            'aurelia-framework',
            'aurelia-history-browser',
            'aurelia-logging-console',
            'aurelia-pal-browser',
            'aurelia-polyfills',
            'aurelia-route-recognizer',
            'aurelia-router',
            'aurelia-templating-binding',
            'aurelia-templating-resources',
            'aurelia-templating-router',
            'bootstrap',
            'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
            'jquery',
            "aurelia-syncfusion-bridge",
            "syncfusion-javascript"      
        ],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist'),
        publicPath: 'dist/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: '[name]_[hash]',
    },
    plugins: [
        extractCSS,
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
        new webpack.DllPlugin({
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
            name: '[name]_[hash]'
        }),
        new ModuleDependenciesPlugin({
            "aurelia-syncfusion-bridge": ["./grid/grid", "./grid/column"],
        }),
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ compress: { warnings: false } })
    ])
}]
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your interest towards Syncfusion controls.

We recommend you to configure aurelia-syncfusion-bridge resources in webpack.config.js file. Because aurelia-syncfusion-bridge’s resources are traced by aurelia-webpack-plugin and included in app.bundle.

Suppose If we add this plugin in webpack.vendor.js, we need to bundle manually for every additional aurelia-syncfusion-bridge’s resources for proper bundling.  Since, we recommend to configure our bridge in webpack.config.js, which will automatically bundle the bridge source along with application bundle.

We have prepared sample for the same and attached below.

[Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/aurelia-webpack1333503894.zip)

Please let us know if you need further assistance on this.

Thanks, 
Abinaya S